# ImageMagick: Convert selective images to Multipage PDF without using external text file?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Let's say I have a directory with 5 TIFF files in it and I want to convert some of them to a multipage PDF, but that there are other TIFS in the same directory that I do not want in the same PDF.

In other words, I want to convert file1.TIF, file2.TIF, file3.TIF --> foo.pdf, but I want to ignore file4.TIF and file5.TIF located in the same folder.

It would seem from the documentation that the only way to do this is to provide ImageMagick with a text file listing out the files and then point to it when calling the program, as in:

```
convert @FilesToConvert.txt C:\foo3.pdf
```

Is there no way to make the call inline though, so that I don't have to create a separate text file for each conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
convert file1.TIF file2.TIF file3.TIF foo.pdf
```